# Webjars-play 2.3.x - Why do we need WebJarAssets.locate and routes.WebJarAssets.at when the path assets/lib/css/filename works

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, webjars

I am bit confused about the Webjars usage in play 2.3.x, I am able to include and webjar and access a js or css file inside it using /assets/lib/css/name in play 2.3.x, however the Webjars site continues to describe about adding a versioned assets configuration in routes file. I am not getting why is this required? Could you please help

Webjars Documentation link: http://www.webjars.org/documentation

Comment: why downvote? Play assets say that it manage Etag by default based on last modified date of the jar. In effective versioned should be same as unversioned in this case. is this understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioned assets allow you to add some optimizations to your static asset loading - e.g. 304 Not Modified and far-future expires.  For more info check out my [Optimizing Static Asset Loading with Play Framework](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/04/29/optimizing-static-asset-loading-with-play-framework) blog.

Comment: Should be taken into account that since play 2.3, there is a integrated way to use asset fingerprinting.